# Timeout when using Google Analytics for crashes and exception reporting with Android

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Looks like GA times out when sending the hits to the servers. This is what I get in logcat:

```
D/GAv4    ( 5725): Hit delivery requested: ht=<numbers>, _s=32, _v=ma8.2.98, a=<numbers>, aid=<package>, an=<app name>, av=1.0, cid=<uuid>, exd=RuntimeException (@<my activity>:onCreate:96) {main}, exf=1, sr=720x1184, t=exception, tid=<tracker ID>, ul=en-us, v=1
D/GAv4    ( 5725): Sync dispatching local hits
W/GAv4    ( 5725): syncDispatchLocalHits timed out: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

And for good measure, this is what my setup looks like (using dagger2 for DI):

AppModule.java:

```
@Provides @Singleton Tracker providesGoogleAnalyticsTracker(App app) {
    return GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(app).newTracker(App.Constants.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID);
}
```

App.java:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Inject Tracker mGoogleAnalyticsTracker;

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        ...
        mGoogleAnalyticsTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
    }
}
```